# How to use parallel processing while reading data from multiple Hive Table for particular database and write in into parquet format

Tags: pyspark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

#### Requirement

How to use parallel processing while reading data from multiple Hive Table for particular database and write in into parquet format.

**Pyspark Code I am using**

```
import pyspark
import sys
database_name = sys.argv[1]

spark.sql("use {}".format(database_name))

df=spark.sql("showtablesin{}".format(database_na))

tableList = [x["tableName"] for x df.collect()]
record = 10


for tablename in tableList: 
  query = spark.sql("SELECT * from {} limit {}".format(tablename,record))
  query.write.mode("append").option("compression","snappy").format("parquet").save("/user/s-migration/rathore_test/{}/{}".format(database_name,tablename))
```

#### Issue

As I am using For loop its taking table record and storing in parquet format. So its sequential. That this why performance is very poor.
I want to know how can I do parallel processing here in this pyspark code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi threading pool too achieved the same.

```
import pyspark
import sys
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
"""Change how may threads to run """ 
pool = ThreadPool(10)
database_name = sys.argv[1]
def parallelwrite(x):
    try:
        query = spark.sql("SELECT * from {} limit {}".format(x,10))
        query.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression","snappy").format("parquet").save("/user/s-migration/rathore_test/{}/{}".format(database_name,tablename))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

spark.sql("use {}".format(database_name))
df=spark.sql("show tables in {}".format(database_name))
tableList = df.select("tableName").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
pool.map( parallelwrite,tableList)
```

Comment: Hi Rafa..Thanks much for your effort. But when I try to execute it with database name as default in databricks community edition. Its giving error like --> name 'tablename' is not defined. So I tried by including for loop in function like     for tablename in tableList:     but its taking long long time for just 5 record.